# How to compile single fortran objects using translator f2c?

Tags: c, matlab, translation, fortran

I have the following problem: I want to simulate some control engineering system. As it is quite complicated I used the computer to derive some (complicated) equations which can only be exported to fortran77 code. On my development pc this is no problem (linux machine).

No I want to do it in hardware and here I have to use a windows OS. Unfortunately matlab does not support gfortran on windows. Therefore I can not compile the fortran files on that box.

My idea was now to translate to C as a C compiler is available at matlab on win. Any other (better) options?

I have several SUBROUTINES in the manner of the following.

```
      SUBROUTINE sys_rhs (x, v, dx, param) 
      REAL*8 x(6)
C     code is coming here
      RETURN
      END SUBROUTINE
```

Is it good practice and does it work to use the function `sys_rhs__` in the interface function written in C?
The problem is, that I can not test it as I do not have massive access to the windows machine. So it should work if I try it and I should not need to experiment a lot.

Also what lib's do I need on windows? Where can I get them?

Thanks
Christian

Comment: Translating to C really seems like the worst option. Depending on your MATLAB version it will support *some* fortran compiler. Since any fortran compiler of the last 10-15 years will compile f77 code, just find another compiler - the one that works with MATLAB and use that one. Or if you have a linux matlab license, use intel's on linux - its free on linux, if memory serves me. Also, this guy supposedly managed to get gfortran/g95+matlab to play nice, so it is possible.

Comment: As I wrote: Under Linux there is no problem at all. I can compile using gfortran and simulate. But the hardware is connected to a win machine... At http://www.mathworks.de/support/compilers/R2010a/win32.html only the propietary intel fortran compiler is mentioned (R2010a is installed by the admin).

Comment: @ChristianWol: it's not very clear from your question, are you talking about creating Fortran MEX-files?

Comment: @Amro: I used a C wrapper around the fortran routines. So I have a "stack" like matlab>>mex>>C wrapper>>fortran on the linux machine. The question is how to change this to be able to run the code under in a win machine I have no root rights and that does not have fortran installed.

Comment: @ChristianWolf - Ah, so in short, you don't have the option of installing a fortran compiler at all? (Intel Fortran compiler I was talking about is proprietary, yes, but under linux it is available for free http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/non-commercial-software-development/)

Comment: @ChristianWolf - Dare I suggest installing linux alongside windows on the mentioned machine (connected to "hardware") - what kind of hardware are we talking about anyway? You/your university really seems to be intentionally taking the hardest route on this ...

Comment: Well, f2c is fine, but possibly not optimal. What libs do you need? How do we know, you've not said what your code does. But if you have no access to the Windows machine then you should give up. Tell them you'll do the work if they let you have access to the tools you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple: I had some syntax errors in my fortran code. `gfortran` does no such strict syntax checking and therefor interpreted the fortran code correctly. After removing the typos I succceded transcoding with f2c.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Intel sells a pretty good fortran compiler (http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fortran-compilers/) which they used to give away for free for testing ... ;-)

PS No, Im not linked to this company in any way!

Comment: Sorry, propietary software is no way because it is not for me personally but for my institute at the university. They are not happy with it as they would have to handle it.

Comment: So if Mathlab can handle code in DLLs (I'm here because of the porting-fortran-to-windows issue not for Mathlab ;-))  I'd propose to look in the already mentioned direction of creating a DLL. This should work using g77 under MingGW or Cygwin running under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check the [gnumex](http://gnumex.sourceforge.net/) project, which allows to compile MEX-files using the GNU GCC compiler suite (using either MinGW or Cygwin), with the ability to use g77 to compile Fortran programs.

Answer (score -1):

there is a better solution to all this

use your linux machine or your windows machine  to implement the function in c/c++ and then generate a dll file. 

 
In matlab you can load the DLL and make a call to the functions inside it.

here is a simple tutorial that show how to call the dll with matlab.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15065-example-of-loading-c-dll-and-performance-comparison

Comment: The function is implemented in fortran as I can only export to fortran in maxima (computer algebra system) as I know. How to generate a dll on linux? MinGW?